# Icon-Picker shows up multiple times after clone-function

Tags: jquery, dom, icons, clone, picker

First of all: sorry for my bad English AND I'm really not a jquery-pro - so please go easy on me.

Here are the most important code-snippets + example... please tell me if you need more to help me.

HTML + inline jquery icon picker:

```
<div class="full" style="margin-bottom: 0;">

                                    <span class="two_fifth first" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <h3 class="skill-item-title">Symbol wählen</h3>
                                    </span>

                                    <span class="three_fifth" style="margin-bottom: 0;">

                                        <input id="icon2" type='' class="criteria_name_two show-tick" name='' style="width: 100%; float: left;" value='' placeholder="">

                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                                        var icons = {
                                            'Webapplikationen' : ['fa fa-car', 'fa fa-caret-square-o-down', 'fa fa-caret-square-o-left']
                                        };
                                        $('#icon2').fontIconPicker({
                                            source: icons,
                                            emptyIcon: true,
                                            hasSearch: true,
                                            allCategoryText: 'Alle Anzeigen',
                                        });
                                    });
                                    </script>
                                    </span>

                                </div>
```

HTML: "Add-Service" (calls the functions below):

```
<div class="option_item">
                        <button type="button" name="submit_add_service" id='submit_add_service' value="add" class="button-secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Service hinzufügen</button>
                    </div>
```

jQuery (Clone):

```
//ADD SERVICE
jQuery('#template_service').hide();
jQuery('#submit_add_service').on('click', function() {      
    $newItem = jQuery('#template_service .option_item').clone().appendTo('#resume_service').show();
    var tmp = $newItem;
    tmp = $.unique( tmp );
    if ($newItem.prev('.option_item').size() == 1) {
        var id = parseInt($newItem.prev('.option_item').attr('id')) + 1;
    } else {
        var id = 0; 
    }
    $newItem.attr('id', id);

    $newItem.find('.skill-item-title span.num').text(id+1);

    var nameText = 'wpjobus_company_services[' + id + '][0]';
    $newItem.find('.criteria_name').attr('id', 'fuck').attr('name', nameText);

    var nameText = 'wpjobus_company_services[' + id + '][1]';
    $newItem.find('.criteria_name_two').attr('id', 'fuck').attr('name', nameText);

    var nameText = 'wpjobus_company_services[' + id + '][2]';
    $newItem.find('.criteria_notes').attr('id', 'fuck').attr('name', nameText);

    var nameText = 'fuck';
    $newItem.find('.criteria_icon').attr('id', 'fuck');

    //event handler for newly created element
    $newItem.children('.button_del_service').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(this).parent('.option_item').remove();
    });

});
```

Example: http://kufifi.at/test/last/2.html

The Problem in a few words:
After I call the Clone() function the picker shows up twice. My guess is that it has something to do with a not yet ready DOM or with multiple ID's but as I said I'm really not good with `jquery` and I'm REALLY at the end with this.

Sorry for the poor code - I "played" around with it really much the last day(s) trying to solve the problem.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks,
NiXxon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT by myself and a little help out of other posts at stackoverflow. If someone is interested: i solved it by adding the following in my clone function:

```
$newItem.find('.criteria_icon').fontIconPicker();
```

sometimes it's more simple then you think...